# Moving Occupied Rows up above Blank ones with VBA code syntax error

Tags: excel, vba, syntax

I have a syntax error in my if statement which I am confused about, seems like the compiler shouldn't require an = but I get an expected : = error on

*if isempty(activecell) then activecell.offset(0,-1)*

```
Range(zen).Select
oak = 1
Do
oak = oak + 1
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)
Else: If IsEmpty(Selection.Offset(0, -1)) Then Copy Selection(activerow(E - M).Range)
Paste Selection.Offset(0, -1)
Loop Until oak = ruby
```

Here is the code in its entirety

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim ruby As Integer
Dim ruby2 As Integer
Set ws = Sheets("Belmont")
Set rng1 = ws.Columns("c").Find("*", ws.[c1], xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
Dim zen As String
zen = rng1.Address(0, 0)
Range(zen).Select
ruby = ActiveCell.Row
ruby2 = ruby - 11
Dim stones() As Boolean
ReDim stones(1 To ruby)
Dim z As Integer
z = 1
Do
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0)) Then
stones(z) = 0
Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
z = z + 1
Else
stones(z) = 1
Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
z = z + 1
End If
Loop Until z > ruby2
Range(zen).Select
oak = 1
Do
oak = oak + 1
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)
Else: If IsEmpty(Selection.Offset(0, -1)) Then Copy Selection(activerow(E - M).Range)
Paste Selection.Offset(0, -1)
Loop Until oak = ruby
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)` is the invalid portion.  You actually need to do something with the `ActiveCell`.  Something like:  `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select` to move the selection to that offset, or `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "data value"` to put data into the offset cell.

Or set a range to that offset cell, like: `Set myRange = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)`

Also, you should change your `If-Then` syntax to be a little more VBA friendly:

```
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
ElseIf IsEmpty(Selection.Offset(0, -1)) Then
    Dim row As Integer
    row = ActiveCell.row
    Range(Cells(row, 5), Cells(row, 13)).Select
    Selection.Copy
End If
```

and `activerow` isn't valid in Excel, so the above changes should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now getting an error saying else without if... can't understand?